# jQuery.cookie saving and loading settings

Tags: jquery, list, cookies, load

I got this runtime dynamic unordered list with .sortable() which I want to store its new listitem order in my cookie after a drag event. On a page reload the saved index values get loaded from the cookie so that the previous changed order gets restored.

```
 <ul id="sortUL">....</ul>

 $.cookie('newItemOrder', $(#sortUL).sortable('serialize'));
```

That gives me a newItemOrder value which looks like this:

```
item[]=4&item[]=1&item[]=3&item[]=2
```

On pageload I get the value from

```
var restoreValues = $.cookie('newItemOrder');
```

But how can I  apply this variable to my UL and LI ? Im kinda stuck here.

Comment: Convert the string to an array, then loop through the array creating ul's and li's.

Comment: hmm yeah I see where you're going. empty() the ul and add the li back in in new order. you think this is the only way ? kinda "not" elegant.  jquery does provide some sort functionality. cant I just go with that somehow ?

Comment: Either way you'll have to convert the string the the array, but instead sort the ul li/s. jQuery doesn't have sort functionality, but you can use [].sort

Comment: i give it a try. Do you think this method of using a cookie is best practice ? Or do you suggest some other way of storing user settings ?